# When using getchar(), why do you need to clear the buffer for the enter key press in the first place?

Tags: c, buffer, getchar

I'm new to programming and learning C:

```
printf("What are your two initials?\n");
firstInit= getchar();
lastInit = getchar();
```

========================================

```
printf("What are your two initials?\n");
firstInit= getchar();
lastInit = getchar();
getchar();
```

I know that in the first section of code, if I type in ZK as initials, the Z will be placed in firstInit, and the '\n\ represented by the enter key will be placed into lastInit. The remaining K would be stored in a subsequent getchar(). However, in the second section of code, the book I'm reading said that if I type in ZK as initials, the firstInit will hold the Z, and the lastInit will hold the K. I just thought that the buffer needed to be cleared after each press of the enter key.

Sorry if this post is not allowed, will delete if needed.

Comment: The reason is most likely due to using one of the 'scanf()' family of functions, previous to calling getchar().  However, this cannot be determined from the snippet of code provided.  Please edit the question and add code sufficient to allow others to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two buffers are in action here: one is Keyboard buffer and another is C standard buffer (input buffer).
When you press the keyboard buttons then the characters stored in keyboard buffer. So when you type `ZK` *together* then it simply stored at keyboard buffer. On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it will goes to C standard buffer with one more character `\n` (generated on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key).
`getchar` reads input character by character. In the first code, the first `getchar` will read `Z` into `firstInit` and second `getchar` will read `K` into `lastInit`. Now, only `\n` is left in the input buffer.
The same is true for second code except that the `\n` is read by third `getchar` and is discarded.

If you press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after each character `Z` and `K`, then you must have to clear input buffer after reading first character to store `K` in `lastInit`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the book I'm reading had an error about getchar(), saying that the first section of code stores '\n' into lastInit.